# When submitting Apns notifications jwt.encode encodes the secret thus rising an exception

Tags: python, exception, cryptography, apple-push-notifications, jwt

I am keeping getting a serialization error when I execute:

```
token = jwt.encode(
{
    'iss': TEAM_ID,
    'iat': time.time()
},
secret,
algorithm= ALGORITHM,
headers={
    'alg': ALGORITHM,
    'kid': APNS_KEY_ID,
})
```

So I investigated the JWT module by printing the data it is going to serialise to check why it rises the exception.

I found the key arrives in byte code possibly as the consequence of the jwt.encode command.

```
 try:
     key = load_pem_public_key(key,  backend=default_backend())
 except ValueError:
      key = load_pem_private_key(key, password=None, backend=default_backend())
```

in file:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py

fails as a consequence. How may I force jwt.encode to leave the secret alone without encoding it?

This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 226, in prepare_key
    key = load_pem_public_key(key, backend=default_backend())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py", line 24, in load_pem_public_key
    return backend.load_pem_public_key(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py", line 314, in load_pem_public_key
    return b.load_pem_public_key(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1111, in load_pem_public_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1326, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not unserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not unserialize key data.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gobikoAPN.py", line 27, in <module>
    'kid': APNS_KEY_ID,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 57, in encode
    json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 98, in encode
    key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 228, in prepare_key
    key = load_pem_private_key(key, password=None, backend=default_backend())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py", line 20, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py", line 305, in load_pem_private_key
    return b.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1085, in load_pem_private_key
    password,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1254, in _load_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1326, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not unserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not unserialize key data.
```

Comment: If that solves the problem you could post an answer.

Comment: Yes, if I manually set the certificate without b in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py I get no error at that point. But that is a dangerous shortcut, should the certificate for some reason change: so that is not an answer proper. How may I submit that certificate in my script without that b to appear when used in the algorithms.py script?

Comment: The `b` stands for bytes, it's not part of the string. You can turn `bytes` to `str` with `decode`

Comment: The problem is that when I print the string in my own code the b is absent, when I do it in the library script it is there. Should I add this decode command in the library script?

Comment: What codec should I use, anyway?

Comment: You can use the [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method. Use it in your script, don't modify the lib code uness you know exactly what you're doing. I may be able to help you more if you include  the full traceback.

Comment: I changed the title and content to better show what is the issue at stake.

Comment: I added the full traceback.

Comment: There seems to be a broblem with `APNS_KEY_ID`, if it's bytes you can try decoding it. Also are you using the correct version of `jwt` for python3? If not you can use: `pip uninstall PyJWT` and `pip uninstall jwt`

Comment: Thanks. Recently I also found a php script for sending the notifications I still need to test being busy in another activity. Should also the php script have problems, I will test your suggestion.